# React + Tailwind CSS: Transition on margin

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions, tailwind-css

I need to add a transition to a margin on an element with Tailwind.
I want the margin to do a transition smoothly.

```html
<div 
  id="thumb" 
  className={`transition-spacing duration-300 ease-in-out ${switchState ? "ml-auto" : "mr-auto"}`}
>
</div>
```

Now it just instantly switches the margin from mr-auto to ml-auto without a transition.
Here is my tailwind config for the transitions:

```js
transitionProperty: {
  width: 'width',
  spacing: 'margin, padding',
}
```

I can verify that the switchState works.
Why doesn't the transition work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can animate properties **only between two numeric values**.

Consider this snippet:

```
<div class="container group">
  <div class="bg-yellow-600 w-12 h-12 ml-0 group-hover:ml-96 transform duration-300"></div>
</div>
```

Briefly, `ml-auto` and `mr-auto` are not proper css properties to animate the element. You need to use absolute positioning or numeric margin definitions.

[Animatable CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)